# EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1 on SecKeyGetBlockSize()

Tags: ios, encryption, keychain

Im trying to add a key into the keychain then encrypt data with it.

```
NSData* peerTag = [@"Test PublicKey" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary * peerPublicKeyAttr = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
 (__bridge id)kSecClassKey, kSecClass,
 (__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA, kSecAttrKeyType,
 (__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyClassPublic, kSecAttrKeyClass,
 peerTag, kSecAttrApplicationTag,
 testPubKey, kSecValueData,
 kCFBooleanTrue, kSecReturnPersistentRef,
                                    nil];

OSStatus sanityCheck = noErr;
sanityCheck = SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) peerPublicKeyAttr);
SecKeyRef persistPeer = NULL;
sanityCheck = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)peerPublicKeyAttr, (CFTypeRef *)&persistPeer);


NSData* passwordData = [@"password" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData* encryptedPass = [[Methods sharedCenter]encrypt:passwordData usingKey:persistPeer];

size_t cipherBufferSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(persistPeer);
```

`SecKeyGetBlockSize(key);` causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1.

I have not worked with this before so im not sure what would cause this error. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you have "key" defined?
Check if it really exists:   if(key) { ...
I think key is not defined or NULL ?

Comment: oh sorry copy paste error. But i think i have fixed the issue, i have to test it later today.

Comment: @Nicolas  what was the fix?  I have my key defined.  But still get this error on same function.